# Getting NetworkOnMainThread exception even after using AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I am trying to send the text to speech result from my android app to my PC over TCP socket. I am implementing it using Async as required.

Here's the `onCreate()` :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sender = new TCPClient("192.168.0.7",2016);
}
```

On receiving the text to speech result I am calling the `execute()` method.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        switch (requestCode) {
        case REQ_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT: {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

                ArrayList<String> result = data
                        .getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                txtSpeechInput.setText(result.get(0));
                sender.execute(result.get(0));
            }
            break;
        }

        }
    }
```

This is my TCPClient class :

```
public class TCPClient extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    protected void onPreExecute1() {}

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}

    PrintWriter out;
    TCPClient(String ip, int port)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket = new Socket(ip,port);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("LINUX","Exception while creating socket");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)
    {
        Log.d("LINUX","Data sent : "+arg0);
        out.println(arg0);
        return "Executed";
    }
}
```

But still I am getting `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Can any one please help me.

Here's the stackTrace :

```
06-23 01:42:03.651: W/System.err(11990): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-23 01:42:03.652: W/System.err(11990):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1161)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:137)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:163)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:590)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.Socket.tryAllAddresses(Socket.java:128)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:178)
06-23 01:42:03.653: W/System.err(11990):    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:150)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at info.androidhive.speechtotext.TCPClient.<init>(TCPClient.java:26)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at info.androidhive.speechtotext.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
06-23 01:42:03.654: W/System.err(11990):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: Only doInBackground is done on background thread,  so what's you expected?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing network I/O in the `TCPClient` constructor. Move all of that to `doInBackground()`. All the constructor should be doing is storing the host and port number in fields of `TCPClient`, so that you can reference their values in `doInBackground()`.

Comment: OK. so should I create socket in `doInBackground()`? If yes, then if I put in `doInBackground()`, won't the socket object will be created every time?

Comment: @InsaneCoder: "so should I create socket in doInBackground()?" -- yes. "won't the socket object will be created every time?" -- yes. Since you cannot reuse an `AsyncTask`, you need to recreate the `Socket` instance every time anyway.

Comment: But I am getting the data over the socket only first time. After that only the log line "Data sent :" is getting printed but no data is recieved over the socket. Can you please help on this or provide answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37977926/android-asynctask-not-working-when-called-multiple-times

Answer (score 0):

`onProgressUpdate` is executed in the UI thread. Try putting the code in `doInBackground` instead.